# C# AddMonths() Exception The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTIme

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have managed to log an error that points to this code

```
DateTime retDate = enddate;
if (enddate.Day > 1)
{
    retDate = enddate.AddDays(1 - enddate.Day).AddMonths(1);
}
```

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value
> results in an un-representable DateTime.  Parameter name: months
> at System.DateTime.AddMonths(Int32 months)

This was logged in db, but I can not reproduce the issue anymore. I have attempted using every date including a new DateTime() but the if check kicks it out.
The logic works as desired but I am just trying to find and create a handle for that edge case.

Comment: Does the code or database use "magic" values like `DateTime.MaxValue` instead of `null` or missing dates? That wouldn't be a good idea. SQL's NULL is *not* the same as a NULL in a programming language. It has a very specific meaning - there's no valid value for that field.

Comment: I see how that could be problematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will give that exception:

```
DateTime enddate = DateTime.MaxValue.AddDays(-1);
DateTime retDate = enddate;

if (enddate.Day > 1)
{
    retDate = enddate.AddDays(1 - enddate.Day).AddMonths(1);
}
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes I see how this could create this exception, I will probably add a handle for this case even though I don't think it is the cause of this issue. 
Mind me asking what is the point of the first like AddDays(-1)

Comment: @FarisKapo The first `AddDays(-1)` is so that `.AddDays(1 - enddate.Day)` does NOT throw an exception. If you try to do `DateTime.MaxValue.AddDays(1)` you would of course get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException of AddMonths() is thrown when the resulting Datetime is less than the MinValue (00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001) or greater than MaxValue (23:59:59.9999999 UTC, 31. Dezember 9999).

Since you add one month, every Date Value between 02. Dezember 9999 and 31.Dezember 9999 in 'enddate' would result in 01. January 10000, which is un-representable.